# Read only таблицы в базе MySql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Подскажите пожалуйста, в **phpmyadmin** - поля в одних таблицах моей БД можно менять, а другие нельзя.

Я так понимаю они **только для чтения**? Как мне поставить нужные мне таблицы для изменения (записи)?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL позволяет управлять правами пользователей БД на уровне сервера, конкретной базы и отдельных таблиц (с указанием конкретных полей).

Вы можете создать пользователя, который может выполнять `SELECT` только в базе `website` для таблицы `users` (причём ограничить выборку только полямм `name` и `id`) и разрешить ему только `UPDATE` поля `name` таблицы `users`.

[image: Выдача привилегий]

Comment: Не могу найти такую табличку в phpmyadmin

Comment: Через root выполнил такие команды в mysql - GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'my_user'@'localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; - не помогло

Comment: А в чём выражается невозможность менять значения?

Comment: ну, к примеру, в phpmyadmin значение полей одних таблиц можно менять - а этих о которых идет речь - нельзя. Через сайт тоже - инфа показывается - а обновить ее нельзя

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась следующей строчкой

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD newid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

ошибка была

> Данное выделение не содержит уникального столбца